# can we make a drone without esc as we use pc fan BLDC moters?

Tags: motor-controller

If we don't want to use esc in making a drone then what effects take place? Can we make a drone without esc?

Comment: Not likely , unless you fully understand specs, PC fans are poor choices.  You need to understand specs like V/F motor DCR and torque, mass/ torque, Hp, blade lift force vs RPM vs power in

Comment: Hard to make a drone without speed control, which is what the ESC (Electronic Speed Control) does.

Answer (score 3):

> If we don't want to use esc in making a drone then what effects take place?

That depends on what you replace it with. But you need some way of accurately controlling several high-power motors, and the most common way that's accomplished is using brushless motors, which require an ESC.

Computer cooling fans are completely unsuitable for use in drones. They cannot be controlled accurately, they have poor aerodynamic characteristics, and they typically do not have enough power to lift even their own weight.

Comment: Not to mention that computer fans typically contain a brushless motor driven by an integrated sensored brushless motor controller (AKA ESC in radio control terminology). If OP dislikes ESCs, OP should discriminate against computer fans as well.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to use a brushless motor, then you need an ESC. They are controlled by fairly complex signals, not just a DC voltage. PC fans are brushless, but already have the ESC built into them.

Depending on the power that you need, and how heavy the drone is going to be, I have seen some good implementations of brushed DC motors used. Even so, these will still need some sort of speed controller to work well. It entirely depends on what you want to make.

Look online, there are plenty of designs and explanations about how these things work, and how to use them.